# How to do in Karate API a Select * from 'somewhere' WHERE email LIKE 'something'?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, karate

I want to retrieve an arraylist with all the ids of the users that have a specific email domain (exe: @generatedEmail.com)

This is an example of how the json would look like; basically a Json Array with Json objects.I need to get a list with the ids of the objects that contain @generatedEmail.com in the email field.

```
[{
        "id": "1234-5678-7890-1231",
        "email": "blabla@generatedEmail.com",
    }, {
        "id": "gsdg4-fc32-dsfs-4213",
        "email": "another@generatedEmail.com",
    },{
        "id": "pgo4-ffx2-621s-gju3",
        "email": "otheremail@dontdelete.com",
    }]
```

My end purpose is to pass this list of ids as parameters to a DELETE endpoint. I found in the Karate documentation that if I pass the list as a parameter when I call the feature file where I describe the Delete steps, it will act as a for each and fire the request for each id in the list.

Thank you in advance!

I tried with different Js functions, but I suck at it and had no success. The below returns to me the emails, but I don't know how to get their related ids. I thought to do the same thing with the ids then match them based on index, but I feel that I would be overengineering it and there must be something simpler and smarter.

```
* def emails = karate.jsonPath(usersList.response,"$..email")
* def condition = function(x){return x.includes('generatedEmail.com')}
```

I also tried this with the belief that I would get an array of the objects that I want from which I can later extract only the ids in another arraylist:

```
* def ids = []
* def fun = function(i){if(i.includes('generatedEmail')) {ids.add(i)}}
* karate.repeat(usersList.response, fun)
```

Then I also tried this but to no avail

```
* eval karate.forEach(usersList.response, function(user){if(user.email.includes('generatedEmail')) { ids.add(user.id)} })
```

---

Please forgive my lack of knowledge and ignorance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for your reference, you can do this in one-line if you are familiar with JS. It is elegant and kind of fun:

```
* def response =
"""
[
  {
    id: '1234-5678-7890-1231',
    email: 'blabla@generatedEmail.com'
  },
  {
    id: 'gsdg4-fc32-dsfs-4213',
    email: 'another@generatedEmail.com'
  },
  {
    id: 'pgo4-ffx2-621s-gju3',
    email: 'otheremail@dontdelete.com'
  }
]
"""
* def filtered = response.filter(x => x.email.includes('@generatedEmail.com')).map(x => x.id)
* match filtered == ['1234-5678-7890-1231', 'gsdg4-fc32-dsfs-4213']
```

Comment: Thank you! This is much more elegant. Karate is amazing!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer to my question.

The function filters and returns all json objects that contain the 'generatedEmail.com' pattern in their email fields.

Then I use the returned list and deepscan it to only retrieve the id fields in another list.

```
* def condition = function(x){return x.email.includes('generatedEmail.com')}
* def filtered = karate.filter(response, condition)
* def ids = karate.jsonPath(filtered,"$..id")
```